# What is shallow copy?

Tags: java, encapsulation, shallow-copy

I created a constructor and, according to my professor, I am violating encapsulation, saying that there is a shallow copy in the constructor. I am writing this question hoping that I might see what I am doing wrong. Because I honestly don't know what it is since my fields are private and I also created getters and setters (not shown).

The Code:

```
public class Class {
    private int difficultyLevel;
    private String subject;
    private List<Student> students;

    public Class(final int theLevel, final String theSubject,
        final List<Student> theStudents) {
    if (theLevel < 0 || theSubject.length() == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    if (theSubject == null || theStudents == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    difficultyLevel = theLevel;
    subject = theSubject;
    students = new ArrayList<Student>(theStudents);

}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Well if the only problem be that you're doing a shallow copy of the incoming students list, then the solution is to just do a deep copy.  Are there any other perceived problems with your code?

Comment: There is nothing so far in your code violating encapsulation principles unless you show us what your `Student` class looks like. Maybe that's what your prof is referring to

Comment: A deep copy might be what the instructor was looking for, but I don't think it has anything to do with the encapsulation of the `Class` class. If the `Student` class is mutable then it makes sense not to make `Class` responsible for managing the state of the `Student` objects. That said, this can't be all of the code for `Class`, because there are no public members here at all. A `Class` object can't be used for anything if there aren't any methods.

Comment: Okay, I finally got it. Thanks all of you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shallow copy is when you copy the references of objects in a data structure instead of copying the objects themselves and saving a copy of them (deep copy)
In this case I guess he is talking about the array of students. He probably wants you to save an array of a copy of each student (new student)

Comment: Array referencing is a perfect example. I would suggest to add a code snippet to make it more clear for further readers who stumble upon this topic in future.

Answer (score 1):

You are just pointing the references or addresses to the old object, that is what shallow copy does.
Just try to perform the deep copy, it will create a new memory space in your project and both will have their own existence in the memory instead of only just reference.

Answer (score 0):

Shallow copy in java means you are just creating a new object that points to the location where the value of old object is stored.
Shallow copy in other words can be said as reference copying.
On shallow copy the objects will be having different memory in stack but same memory in heap. Hence you will be having two copies but any changes applied on one can be seen on other also.